# How do I make a dynamic image in Java Swing?

Tags: java

How can i make my image dynamic; My code :

```
public void paint(Graphics g){
    super.paint(g);

    //this.setBackground(Color.white);
    g.drawImage(bg,300 , 70, 800, 100, null);
}
```

That creates an image but when i open the window and i enlarge it; the images takes the right position.

Comment: Hint: you should include a clear description of the intended behavior as well. I am not sure what you are asking for.

Comment: I am sorry ... i just need my image to have a dynamic change ..when i open my window the image position on the middle ... i want it to stay in the middle when i enlarge the window

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First look at the method you are calling.

`drawImage(Image img, int x, int y, int width, int height, ImageObserver observer)`

It sounds like you need to know x and y values to paint your image in the correct location. Lets pretend this paint method is inside of a component.

```
//based on your description.
int imageWidth = 800;
int imageHeight = 100;
int x = (getWidth() - imageWidth)/2;
int y = (getHeight() - imageHeight)/2;
g.drawImage(bg, x, y, imageWidth, imageHeight, this);
```

That should center your image when the component is resized and repainted. Of course there are better ways to do this, such as using a JLabel and a layout manager.